# Discord.JS Get First Attachment in Message

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord, discord.js

I just want to use my Discord.JS bot to get the first attachment in a [message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) ([MessageAttatchment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) object), simply put. I have already tried this, but it just seems to crash immediately.

```
  var Attachment = (message.attachments)
  if (Attatchment){
    console.log( Attatchment.array()[0] )
    console.log( Attatchment.array()[0].url )
  }
```

The crash might not be due to this, it could be due to relevant code surrounding the area, but this is not a problem, since if I find a solution, that relevant code will become irrelevant.

Comment: You seem to have misspelt `Attachment` in most of your code.

Comment: Well, that might fix things...! Let me try that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is 2 years old, but I think I might of found the problem. You seem to have mistyped the variable attachment, instead of attachment, you types in attatchment.

This is how the code should look like. Although, not sure if there may be more errors, this code snippet just fixes the typos.

```
var Attachment = (message.attachments)
if (Attachment){
    console.log( Attachment.array()[0] )
    console.log( Attachment.array()[0].url )
}
```

There is a comment on it that does point it out, but they haven't considered it as an answer.

**Tip:** Always try to check for typos in your code, that is the most common problem. Use the Find tool in a text editor to help find typos.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution, lol... in my past _naïveté_ I somehow did not consider typos as a possible issue, and I figured that was so boldly apparent that I didn't need to mark an answer as correct. Anyways, great response, I hope you keep giving advice to other users on the platform!

Comment: I'll try my best to give advice to other users.

Answer (score 3):

> There's a [`Attachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) class in **discord.js**. So, it will create a conflict between variables definitions.
>   You should rename it to something else!